# Unable to create new project in Android Studio, getting malformed input error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using `android studio 3.0`. Whenever I try to create a new project, I get this error:

```
Gradle 'MyActivity' project refresh failed, Error:Cause: malformed input around byte 13
```

I'm unable to fix this because it is related to `gradle`. I've followed certain steps to fix it which are given below.
I've added a screen shot.
[image: SS]
Log is as given below:

```
2018-03-21 10:41:48,786 [thread 206]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-03-21 10:41:48,786 [thread 206]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-03-21 10:41:48,786 [thread 206]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-03-21 10:41:48,786 [thread 206]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-03-21 10:41:49,952 [se-915-b01]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'MyActivity'. 
2018-03-21 10:41:49,980 [thread 206]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-03-21 10:41:49,987 [thread 206]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-03-21 10:41:50,019 [thread 206]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.local.repo contents "allprojects {\n  buildscript {\n    repositories {\n      maven { url 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\gradle\\\\m2repository'}\n    }\n  }\n  repositories {\n      maven { url 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\gradle\\\\m2repository'}\n  }\n}\n" 
2018-03-21 10:41:50,019 [thread 206]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.version=3.0 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.0.0.18 --init-script C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.local.repo1148.gradle --init-script C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit13.gradle 
2018-03-21 10:41:50,051 [thread 206]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:258)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:902)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not read cache value from 'C:\Users\kulkaa\.gradle\daemon\4.1\registry.bin'.
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.deserialize(SimpleStateCache.java:139)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.access$000(SimpleStateCache.java:33)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache$1.create(SimpleStateCache.java:49)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.readFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:170)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.readFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:38)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.get(SimpleStateCache.java:47)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.get(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getAll(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:138)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:208)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 13
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:656)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.InputStreamBackedDecoder.readString(InputStreamBackedDecoder.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DefaultDaemonContext$Serializer.read(DefaultDaemonContext.java:93)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DefaultDaemonContext$Serializer.read(DefaultDaemonContext.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonInfo$Serializer.read(DaemonInfo.java:131)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonRegistryContent$Serializer.readInfosMap(DaemonRegistryContent.java:138)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonRegistryContent$Serializer.read(DaemonRegistryContent.java:118)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonRegistryContent$Serializer.read(DaemonRegistryContent.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.deserialize(SimpleStateCache.java:134)
    ... 31 more
2018-03-21 10:41:50,051 [thread 206]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: malformed input around byte 13 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: malformed input around byte 13
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:85)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:414)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:906)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 13
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:656)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.InputStreamBackedDecoder.readString(InputStreamBackedDecoder.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DefaultDaemonContext$Serializer.read(DefaultDaemonContext.java:93)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DefaultDaemonContext$Serializer.read(DefaultDaemonContext.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonInfo$Serializer.read(DaemonInfo.java:131)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonRegistryContent$Serializer.readInfosMap(DaemonRegistryContent.java:138)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonRegistryContent$Serializer.read(DaemonRegistryContent.java:118)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonRegistryContent$Serializer.read(DaemonRegistryContent.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.deserialize(SimpleStateCache.java:134)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.access$000(SimpleStateCache.java:33)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache$1.create(SimpleStateCache.java:49)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.readFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:170)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.readFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:38)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.get(SimpleStateCache.java:47)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.get(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getAll(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:138)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:208)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    ... 3 more
```

**Steps:**
I tried to fix it by clearing `gradle` cache and `lock` file. But it didn't work. I even uninstalled and reinstalled Android studio, but that didn't fix this problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try to delete the directory `C:\Users\kulkaa\.gradle\daemon\4.1`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by moving `.Gradle` folder to different location, then I restarted android studio, let android studio download required gradle files and build new project. It worked. But that malformed error was weird.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the contents of folder daemon worked for me.

Folder location is: `C:\Users\kulkaa\.gradle\daemon\**`

Before I was deleting the entire `.gradle` folder and having Android studio reinstall gradle, which was a royal pain.